# I am unable to link href tag inside php

Tags: php, laravel, href

I am trying to redirect the users based on the roles but I can not add an `href` tag inside the PHP tag for some reason.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>


                <?php if(auth()->user()->isAdmin == 1){?>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                  <a href="{{url('admin/routes')}}"> Welcome to the Admin panel!</a>
                </div><?php } else echo "<div class='panel-heading'> <a href='{{url(route('blog'))}}'>Normal User</a></div>";?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to generate HTML from /inside/ the php tag, you need to do it in php, i.e. with echo.

Comment: Is isAdmin a function?

Comment: the problem that I'm having is that the route added in the href in the else section does not show as a link. rest works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these methods to create html link in php

```
<?php
    echo "<a href='https://www.google.com' target='_blank'>Text</a>";

    $link = "<a href='https://www.quora.com' target='_blank'>Text</a>";
    ?>
```

Or you can try this markup too

```
"<td><a href='http://yourlink'>delete</a></td>";
```

Comment: while technicaly valid, using a td without a table is no good from w3c standard point of view https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#tree-construction